# Who can help me with the LIRC config for AEG Hood with Hob2Hood functionality?

Tags: raspberry-pi, infrared

Has someone already had success in retrieving the LIRC codes for AEG Hood with Hob2Hood functionality?

I've allready found the following codes:

---

```
FAN_1       0xE3C01BE2
FAN_2       0xD051C301    
FAN_3       0xC22FFFD7    
FAN_4       0xB9121B29
FAN_OFF     0x55303A3
LIGHT_ON    0xE208293C
LIGHT_OFF   0x24ACF947
```

However I still need more info for config file. Fi. which protocol is used (NEC, Sony, RC5 etc.) and also which frequency, header, one, zero, ptrail etc. to configure the LIRC config file properly.

Who can help?

Comment: where did you get the codes? ... FAN_OFF is missing a digit

Answer (score 1):

Complete description and example program can be found here:
https://www.elektormagazine.nl/labs/hob2hood-interface-investigation

Comment: Welcome to Internet of Things! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.